# asp mvc, having trouble understanding composite models

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to learn how to make a basic ASP MVC wizard application with multiple models and am playing around with some example projects.  I started with this as I am a beginner:  http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/9a5fe277-6e7e-43e5-8408-a28ff5be7801.aspx

I have 3 strongly typed partial views, BasicDetails, AddressDetails, and ContactDetails that the user scrolls through as divs on the Index page using JQuery.  I want each partial view to have it's own model / database table and after scrolling through all of the partial views, I want to display all of them on one review page before writing them all to their respective database tables.  I thought I would accomplish this by using a composite model but am so far unsuccessful.

My model classes, all in one file Customer.cs:

```
public class Customer
{
    public BasicDetails BasicDetails { get; set; }
    public AddressDetails AddressDetails { get; set; }
    public ContactDetails ContactDetails { get; set; }
}

public class BasicDetails
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class AddressDetails
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}

public class ContactDetails
{
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
}
```

HomeController.cs:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Customer obj)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View("Review", obj);
        }
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Review(Customer obj)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Index.aspx:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)){%>

<div id="divBasic" class="index">
<% Html.RenderPartial("BasicDetails"); %>
</div>

<div id="divAddress" class="index">
<% Html.RenderPartial("AddressDetails"); %>
</div>

<div id="divContact" class="index">
<% Html.RenderPartial("ContactDetails"); %>
</div>

<%}%>
```

JQuery for scrolling:

```
$("div.index").hide();
$("div.index:first").show();
$("div.index :button[value='Next'],:button[value='Previous']").click(function () {
    var parentDiv = $(this).parent();
    $("div.index").hide();
    if ($(this).val() == "Previous") {
        var prevDiv = parentDiv.prev();
        prevDiv.show();
    }
    if ($(this).val() == "Next") {
        var nextDiv = parentDiv.next();
        nextDiv.show();
    }
});
```

Review.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication2.Models.Customer>" %>
...

<fieldset>
    <legend>Fields</legend>

    <div class="display-label">CustomerID</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.BasicDetails.CustomerID %></div>

    <div class="display-label">CompanyName</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.BasicDetails.CompanyName %></div>

    <div class="display-label">Address</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.AddressDetails.Address %></div>

    <div class="display-label">City</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.AddressDetails.City %></div>

    <div class="display-label">Country</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.AddressDetails.Country %></div>

    <div class="display-label">PostalCode</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.AddressDetails.PostalCode %></div>

    <div class="display-label">ContactName</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.ContactDetails.ContactName %></div>

    <div class="display-label">Phone</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.ContactDetails.Phone %></div>

    <div class="display-label">Fax</div>
    <div class="display-field"><%: Model.ContactDetails.Fax %></div>

</fieldset>
```

BasicDetails:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.Models.BasicDetails>" %>

<h1>Step 1 : Basic Details</h1>
<%= Html.LabelFor(m=>m.CustomerID) %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.CustomerID) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.CustomerID) %><br />
<%= Html.LabelFor(m=>m.CompanyName) %>
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.CompanyName) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.CompanyName) %><br />

<input type="button" name="nextBtn" value='Next' />
```

AddressDetails:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.Models.AddressDetails>" %>

<h1>Step 2 : Address Details</h1>
<%= Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Address) %><br />
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Address) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Address) %> 
<br />
<%= Html.LabelFor(m=>m.City) %><br />
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.City) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.City) %> 
<br />
<%= Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Country) %><br />
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Country) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Country) %> 
<br />
<%= Html.LabelFor(m=>m.PostalCode) %><br />
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.PostalCode) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.PostalCode) %><br /> 
<br />
<input type="button" name="prevBtn" value='Previous' />
<input type="button" name="nextBtn" value='Next' />
```

ContactDetails:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<MvcApplication2.Models.ContactDetails>" %>

<h1>Step 3 : Contact Details</h1>
<%= Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ContactName) %><br />
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.ContactName) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ContactName) %> 
<br />
<%= Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Phone) %><br />
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Phone) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Phone) %> 
<br />
<%= Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Fax) %><br />
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Fax) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Fax) %> <br />
<br />
<input type="button" name="prevBtn" value='Previous' />
<input type="submit" name="nextBtn" value='Finish' />
```

So I have a few questions:

Question1:
If I do it this way, I get a an error on submit that says, "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" for "Model.BasicalDetails.CustomerID" in Review.  Do I need to assign BasicDetails, AddressDetails, and ContactDetails to each of the Customer members, and if so, where?

Question2:
If I change my Customer model to:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string SalesRep { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
}

public class BasicDetails
{
    public string SalesRep { get; set; }
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

public class AddressDetails
{
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
}

public class ContactDetails
{
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Fax { get; set; }
}
```

...instead of having BasicDetails, AddressDetails, and ContactDetails as members to just having all of the same fields as the other three classes, and in Review change for example Model.AddressDetails.City to just Model.City, and leave everything else the same, it works.  Why would that work?  When entering info in the partial views, how does it know to also update Customer?

Thank you for any and all advice.

Comment: you need to pass the empty model to your view, and in turn pass each sub-model to each partial view

Comment: Use editor templates.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with the old Razor syntax, but your model and Views look okay. The issue is in your controller. With a number of things to change. Before I get to it, why are you not saving your `Customer` entity to your DB during the `POST` action?

What you are trying to do is then easily accomplished with EF

Comment: @AbdulG I was taking an incremental approach to learning this, and so right now I'm just trying to get all of the models or composite model to that last review page to display as details, then was going to approach the problem of writing to the DB after that. EDIT: Also, I was planning on Review being a details page giving the user the option of either accepting the data, and then writing to the DB with another confirming submit, or going back and editing what they entered.  Thanks for your response!

Comment: @Jonesy  Than you for the response!  Would I pass the empty model in the controller for `Index()`?  Like `return View(obj)` where `obj` is a new `Customer`?  Then, for passing the sub-models to the partial views, doesn't that already happen by them being strongly typed, or am I misunderstanding that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, initialize your properties in your composite model:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        BasicDetails = new BasicDetails();
        AddressDetails = new AddressDetails();
        ContactDetails = new ContactDetails();
    }

    public BasicDetails BasicDetails { get; set; }
    public AddressDetails AddressDetails { get; set; }
    public ContactDetails ContactDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Next, if you don't specify the model when rendering a partial view, the main view's model is passed in, so you want to specify the actual model the partial should be working with, i.e.:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("BasicDetails", Model.BasicDetails); %>
```

Do the same with your other partials and you should be fine.

Comment: Ok, so I'm trying this out.  I had to type my index page as `Customer` for it to recognize `Model.BasicDetails` and add `Customer c = new Customer(); return View(c);` to my home controller to avoid a null reference.  Does that sound right?  Then it works up until my review page; all of my fields, like `Model.BasicDetails.CustomerID ` just return blank there.  Is there something else I'm missing?  Thanks again for the responses.

Comment: In general, if you're going to do something like a "review" step, then you want to place the posted data in `TempData` and then return your `Review` view. Placing the data in `TempData` will keep it around until the next request (user clicking "Confirm" or whatever), and then you can save it. Otherwise, you need to create hidden fields or something on the review page so that you post all the data back again when the user confirms.

Comment: So the only way I could get this to work was to, in all of my partial views, type them "Customer" and then do my fields like:  `<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AddressDetails.Address)%>`.  And then everything worked.  Not sure which way I like best, but thanks for giving me an alternative.

Comment: Because you didn't pass in the particular sub-"model" to your partial. Take another look at the sample code i gave you above, particularly the line with `Html.RenderPartial`.